# Nonblocking open() blocks on NFS filesystem when server down

Tags: io, blocking, nonblocking, nfs

I am on CentOS 6.4 and using NFSv4. I am aware that with the default "hard" mount option, if the NFS server becomes inaccessible then processes on the client trying to access the NFS filesystem go to indefinite sleep. What I was not aware of is that even a non-blocking open() can block!

```
const char *path = "/path/to/file/on/nfs";
fd = open(path, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

This has come as a surprise. The open(2) man page, for the O_NONBLOCK entry starts as: "When possible, the file is opened in non-blocking mode..." The "When possible" qualification does not give any consolation.

Is this the expected behavior? Is there no work-around? I don't want to use the "soft" mount option because there exists enough advice on the Net against using it. Moreover, even with "soft" the application would still block for sometime, which is unneeded.

Comment: shiii* Same problem. Repost on unix.stackexchange?